# How to prevent named anchor jump/scroll in main page using easytabs jQuery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here's a [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/naa22prw/2/) to demonstrate the problem.

I have a fixed position floating/popup dialog on my page that contains a series of tabs using the easytabs jQuery plugin. When the dialog appears, any tab selection causes the webpage (behind the floating dialog) to jump/scroll to a different position on the page.

I've read in other places that forcing the click behavior of the anchor tags in the tab structure to prevent the default behavior will correct this issue, but it doesn't seem to be working for me e.g. assigning a class such as `.prevent-default` to each tab anchor element and doing:

```
$('.prevent-default').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Here's some html:

```
<h1>Top</h1><button onclick="showTabDialog();">Tabs</button>
<p id="spacer"></p>
<h1>Bottom</h1>

<div id="dialog" class="floating-dialog"> 

    <div id="tabs" class="tab-container">
        <ul class="tabs">
            <li class="tab">
                <a href="#first" class="prevent-default">First</a>
            </li>
            <li class="tab">
                <a href="#second" class="prevent-default">Second</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <div id="content-container">
            <div id="first" class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-no-data">No data yet</div>
            </div>
            <div id="second" class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-no-data">No data yet</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

...and some js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tabs').easytabs({animationSpeed: 'fast'});
    $('.prevent-default').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
});

function showTabDialog() {
    $('#dialog').fadeIn();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('#tabs').easytabs({animationSpeed: 'fast', updateHash: false});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/naa22prw/3/

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is to set a minimum height on the tabs container div. `

```
#tab-container{
  min-height: 700px;
}
```

This means that you can use the `updateHash: true` so the URL can change each time a tab is clicked.

ref. https://github.com/JangoSteve/jQuery-EasyTabs/issues/40